# How do I stop Doctrine from quoting numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to run a native SQL query using doctrine and am running into problems with it quoting the numbers for the `LIMIT` part of my query.

```
    $offset = $pageNumber * self::$limit;

    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM devices LIMIT :offset, :limit
    ";
    $stmt = self::getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue("offset", $offset);
    $stmt->bindValue("limit", self::$limit);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Generates:

```
SELECT * FROM devices LIMIT '0', '5000'
```

Which is not valid. ***I'm a little stumped on how I can alter this to produce***:

```
SELECT * FROM devices LIMIT 0, 5000
```

I've referenced [data-retrieval-and-manipulation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) which has a section about the `quote()` functions, but it's shy on details.

Comment: I am sorry. My answer was incorrect. I don't carrefully read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
$stmt->bindValue("offset", $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

See source [here](http://www.igestis.org/api/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Driver.Mysqli.MysqliStatement.html#106):

```
 28: class MysqliStatement implements \IteratorAggregate, Statement
 29: {
 30:     protected static $_paramTypeMap = array(
 31:         PDO::PARAM_STR => 's',
 32:         PDO::PARAM_BOOL => 'i',
 33:         PDO::PARAM_NULL => 's',
 34:         PDO::PARAM_INT => 'i',
 35:         PDO::PARAM_LOB => 's' // TODO Support LOB bigger then max package size.
 36:     );
```

Comment: Thanks! The doctrine docs completely gloss over the `PDO::PARAM_X` values.